# Get array of values from array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a array like this

```
arr = [{:id=>1}, {:id=>2}, {:id=>3}, {:id=>4}, {:id=>5}, {:id=>6}, {:id=>7}, {:id=>8}]
```

The result should be

```
result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I used `arr.map { |i| i.values }`.However, the result is `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]`. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *flatten* the result, to get your desired output :

```
arr.flat_map { |i| i.values }
```

Read [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

I don't know actual intention of yours, still if you want to collect all **ids**, you can write :

```
arr.collect { |h| h[:id] }
```

Comment: Or short form: `arr.flat_map(&:values)`

Answer (score 0):

use `flatten` For return an one-dimensional a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this array (recursively)

```
 arr.map {|i| i.values}.flatten
```

Or simply map all `ids`

```
arr.collect {|i| i[:id]}
```